# code first to existing database missing from wizard selection

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, platform-update-1

In the [video here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Code-First-to-Existing-Database-EF6-1-Onwards-) the Entity Data Model Wizard includes options "EF Designer from database" and "Code First from database"

I do not get these options appearing in the wizard when I add a new data item and select ADO.Net entity data model

I am using VS2013 and have installed EF6.1 using Nuget.  How do I install the new wizard options?

in VS Help About reports

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938

Installed Version: Professional

LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2013

Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 ENU

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2013

Visual Basic 2013   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft Visual Basic 2013

Visual C# 2013   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft Visual C# 2013

Visual C++ 2013   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013

Visual F# 2013   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft Visual F# 2013

Visual Studio 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker   06177-004-0447006-02694
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2013 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.21001.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.0.11213.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

BusinessObjectEditor   1.0
Information about my package

Common Azure Tools   1.0
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Windows Azure Tools.

CreateLayoutWizard   1.0
Create layout wizard.

DevExpress.DeploymentTool   1.0
A useful tool for deploying DevExpress assemblies.

DevExpress.ExpressApp.Design.DesignDynamicPackage   1.0
DevExpress VSIX Package

DevExpress.ExpressApp.DesignPackage   1.0
DevExpress VSIX Package

DevExtreme.Design   14.1.7
DevExtreme Visual Studio integration package

JetBrains ReSharper 8.2   Full Edition build 8.2.0.2160 on 2014-03-20T08:53:08
JetBrains ReSharper 8.2 package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For more information about ReSharper, visit http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/. Copyright © 2003–2014 JetBrains, Inc.

Microsoft Web Developer Tools 2013   2.0.40926.0
Microsoft Web Developer Tools contains the following components:
Support for creating and opening ASP.NET web projects
Browser Link: A communication channel between Visual Studio and browsers
Editor extensions for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript
Page Inspector: Inspection tool for ASP.NET web projects
Scaffolding: A framework for building and running code generators
Server Explorer extensions for Windows Azure Web Sites
Web publishing: Extensions for publishing ASP.NET web projects to hosting providers, on-premises servers, or Windows Azure

NuGet Package Manager   2.8.50126.477
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   12.0.30919.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TechTalk SpecFlow   1.9.3
TechTalk SpecFlow - Binding business requirements to .NET code, http://www.specflow.org
Copyright © 2009–2013 TechTalk

Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.0
Windows Azure Mobile Services Tools

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.

XtraReports package   1.0
XtraReports package
```

Comment: Do you have the latest quarterly update for Visual Studio? Look for the little flag in the upper right corner which will tell you if you need to update any components or VS2013.

Comment: When I hold the mouse over the little flag it says "No Notifications"  I updated the question with the version information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the latest quarterly update for Visual Studio? Look for the little flag in the upper right corner which will tell you if you need to update any components or VS2013.

You are running update 1. Update 3 is the latest stable release which can be downloaded:

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43721)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate and Quick Solution ->

For me, it worked there by downloading & installing EFTools6.1.3ForVS2013.msi (19.6 MB) version from Microsoft Download page for [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012 & 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762)